# Spin up all raid drives at the same time

Tags: software-raid, hdparm

Here is the configuration:

- 4 HDDs in a RAID-5 array (mdadm)
- hdparm `spin_down_time` set for all disks
- Debian jessie 8.11

When the drives are in standby mode and the RAID array is requested, they wake up *"sequentially"*, one after another.
It makes the access delayed for many seconds.

Is there a way to make all the drives spin up at the same time ?

Comment: Why have the drives spun down? Just fix that problem.

Comment: @michael-hampton When the server is left idle for a while, the drives go into standby mode (spin down). This is the hdparm expected behavior.

Comment: That is _not_ normal behavior. The drives should always be spinning.

Comment: It is normal behavior -- the intention is not to put unnecessary wear and tear on the drive's motor or other components. A solution would be to use SSD's instead which have no "spin-up time" or spinning components to wear out.

Answer (score 2):

The drive does a staggered spinup likely because you access sequential data chunks. Suppose having a stripe size of 64K (single disk chunk size of 16K): a single 64K read will sequentially wake all disks.

To avoid spinning down the disks you can use `hdparm -B 128` to selectively disable spin down only. For maximum performance you can issue `hdparm -B 255`, which completely disables any power-saving measures.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it makes sense. mdadm tries to read the first chunk on the first drive, waits for it to be available, then tries to read the next one. Then I don't think there is any mdadm/hdparm option that could help (without disabling spinning down). Do you ?

Comment: on an RAID and what you called "server" disk never spinning down